# How to store ArrayList<LatLng> on Sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I'm developing an app that tracks user movement. On each `onLocationChanged()` I store the latitude and longitude in `ArrayList<latLng>` and than draw a polyline on the route. Now, when `activity` stopped I want to save all users activity information like:

- distance
- average pace
- duration
- all ArrayList latlng points of activity

on `Sqlite` database to restore it later and draw a polyline with this points.
The problem that I have no idea how to store the `ArrayList` of latitude and longitude to the database.
Anyone can help?

My solution edit, maybe will help someone!

```
public class SQLUtils extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "data.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String run_table = "Run_table";
private static final String locationPoints = "Location_points";

public SQLUtils(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d("DB", "onCreate");

    String runTable = "create table " + run_table + "(ID VARCHAR(10), PACE VARCHAR(10), DURATION VARCHAR(10), DISTANCE VARCHAR(10), DATE VARCHAR(10), TIME VARCHAR(10));";
    String LocationTable = "create table " + locationPoints + "(ID INTEGER, POSITION INTEGER, Latitude REAL, Longitude REAL);";

    db.execSQL(runTable);
    db.execSQL(LocationTable);
}

public void insertRunData(String id, String pace,String duration, String distance, String date, String time) {
    Log.d("DB", "onInsertRunData");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "INSERT into " + run_table +
        " (ID, PACE, DURATION, DISTANCE, DATE, TIME) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + pace + "','" + duration + "','" + distance +
           "','" + date + "','" + time + "')";

    db.execSQL(sql);

    db.close();
}

    public void insertLatLng(String id, int position, double latitude, double longitude){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "INSERT into " + locationPoints +
            " (ID, POSITION, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE) VALUES ('" + UUID.fromString(id) + "','" + Integer.toString(position) + "','"
             + String.valueOf(latitude) + "','" + String.valueOf(longitude) + "')";

    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.close();
}
```

Run fragment class:

```
    private void saveSqlRun() {
    SQLUtils sqlUtils = new SQLUtils(getActivity());
    sqlUtils.insertRunData(currentRun.getId(), currentRun.getAveragePace(), currentRun.getRunDuration(),
            currentRun.getRunDistance(), currentRun.getRunDate(),currentRun.getRunTime());

    /* Save user Location points */
    for (int index = 0; index < currentRun.getLocationPoints().size(); ++index) {
        sqlUtils.insertLatLng(currentRun.getId(), index, currentRun.getLocationPoints().get(index).latitude, currentRun.getLocationPoints().get(index).longitude);
    }
}
```

Thats how run_rable looks:
[image]

Thats how Location_points looks:
[image]

Comment: Loop over the arraylist and store each entry by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read about [Sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Then you should read about [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

After you understood how to use `sqlite` with android, design your tables. I'm guessing that you will have a table with columns:

```
 id, userId, lat, lng, timeStamp.
```

Now you can easily get for each user where he was and when and calculate all the rest.

To give you a small hint of how to store `ArrayList` then use something like:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops
for (LatLng latLng : list) {
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.insert(Uri).withValue("userId", userId).withValue("lat", 32.3232)...build()
} 

getActivity().getContentResolver().applyBatch("AUTHORITY", ops)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried something different and it works! I'll be glad if you look at my edited post and apply that is good solution or not!

Comment: well...you should keep in the db the minimum viable information. in your case you are keeping data that is easily calculated. keep only the data that you need (as i've suggested you) and calculate other variables as needed

Comment: Also i know that now you think it's an overkill but do study about `Content Providers`. it's worth the extra millage

Comment: @royB, would you opt to store an array list of points, or as the TS does saving each individual point as a row. Any thoughts or tips to share? Kind regards